# Clifford group quantum operations and classical computation

Tags: quantum-computing

The [Clifford group](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0603226) of quantum operators is generated by the quantum operations:

- *Controlled-Z*,
- *Hadamard*, and
- *Phase* ($= |0\rangle\langle0| + i |1\rangle\langle1|$).

A circuit composed only of these gates can be simulated efficiently on a classical computer. However, if I understand correctly, not all classical algorithms can be implemented efficiently using Clifford group operations, at least as far as we know.

Is there a construction to implement, even inefficiently or approximately, a classical algorithm using Clifford group operations?
For instance, how do you implement a *Toffoli* gate using Clifford group gates, if it's possible?

Comment: Quantum Toffoli gate is universal for quantum computation while Clifford group gates are not universal.

Comment: In my understanding, Toffoli gate alone isn't universal for efficient quantum computation, since it takes computational basis states into other computational basis states.

Comment: Toffoli + Clifford group is universal for efficient quantum computation, if I understand correctly

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment above, if it were possible to coherently implement a Toffoli gate using Clifford group gates, then the Clifford group would be universal for quantum computation. It was noted in Section 5 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1467) that something even stronger is true: informally speaking, if there exists a class of quantum circuits which can be simulated efficiently classically, and which is universal for *classical* computation, then BQP=BPP. Thus we would expect simulable classes of quantum circuits not to be universal for classical computation.

Clifford group circuits themselves are particularly weak, and correspond to the complexity class Parity-L, as was shown [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406196).

Comment: Thanks for the references. Now that you mention, I seem to remember that Nielsen & Chuang describe a Toffoli + Clifford group construction that is universal for quantum computation (I can't access the book at the moment).

Comment: Indeed, even just having Toffoli and Hadamard gates is enough (see the paper quant-ph/0301040, for instance).

Comment: Please consider joining: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ .